# Web API JSON deserialization calls getters before setters

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, lazy-loading

I have a class called Menu. Menu has a private list variable _Sections and a public list variable sections. I am using the following pattern for lazy loading. This also allows me to retrieve child items when serializing

```
public class Menu 
{
    public int Id;
    private List<MenuSection> _Sections = null;
    public List<MenuSection> Sections
    {
        get
        {
            return _Sections ?? (_Sections = MenuSection.GetListByMenu(Id)); //database call
        }
        set
        {
            _Sections = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I then modify the collection client side and send it back to the API as JSON.

My problem is that the getter for Sections is called before the setter. This means that the collection is refilled from the database and then has my now updated sections appended.

I've created the following work around, but it's ugly and I don't want to have to remember to do it everywhere I want to lazy load.

```
public class Menu 
{
    public int Id;
    private bool deserialized = false;

    [OnDeserializing()]
    internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        DeserializerCalled = true;
    }

    private List<MenuSection> _Sections = null;
    public List<MenuSection> Sections
    {
        get
        {
            return _Sections ?? (_Sections = DeserializerCalled ? new List<>() : MenuSection.GetListByMenu(Id));
        }
        set
        {
            _Sections = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing some property attribute or global JSON setting that will resolve this for me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your getter is actually setting the variable, you are just fighting the framework. The get block should just return the value of the _Sections collection. Why not considering in using the Lazy construct introduced in C# 4 ?

```cs
private Lazy<List<MenuSection>> _someVariable = new Lazy<List<MenuSection>>(() => MenuSection.GetListByMenu(id));

public string SomeVariable => _someVariable
```

As a side note, I suggest to follow the right naming convention here and have the private member in camel case: _sections.

Comment: the Lazy value factory doesn't allow me to pass in my non-static id

Comment: I updated the answer for that as well. Just use a lambda expression. @Broom

Comment: I tried that. The anonymous function can't be used here. I was able to get it to assign that way in the constructor, however it is already too late by then.